# C# - jqGrid Fill data with JSON array

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have to fill the `jqGrid` with the data coming from the `C#` server in `JSON` fromat like this.

```
object
{
    page:1,
    total:7,
    rowModel:[
        array[0]:{
            object{         
                text="myText"
            },
        },
        array[1]:{
            object[0]{   //Header for the column 1      
                text="1"
            },
            object[1]{  //Header for the column 2       
                text="2"
            },
        }
    ],
    rows:[
        object[0]{   //Suppose this object have the data for Page 1...      
            text="1",
            value="OKAY"
        },
        object[1]{  //Suppose this object have the data for Page 2...       
            text="2",
            value="NOT OKAY"
        },
        object[2]{  //Suppose this object have the data for Page 3...
            text="3",
            value="Fail"
        },
    ]
}
```

1. How can I set the `JSONData` to `jqGrid`
2. How to set `pages`
3. I want to set pages as number of as `Object` comes under the `Rows` array.

[image]

Comment: Is that `object { ... }` string supposed to be JSON?  Because it isn't, for instance it fails validation at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  If that's the output of some visualizer, can you please edit your question to share the actual literal JSON string?

Comment: You can see here http://imgur.com/kHlHQvQ the screenshot of `Browser's log`.

Comment: @dbc, I update the my question, Please help me to solve this problem.